# Where to find documentation on `react-native.config.js` file?

Tags: react-native, configuration, react-native-cli

I have created new React Native project using its CLI. One of the generated files is `react-native.config.js`. I cannot find any documentation on it. It's not mentioned on the [React Native website](https://reactnative.dev/) and I couldn't find documentation for the CLI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`react-native-config.js` is used by the React Native CLI. You can read about it in the CLI docs here: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/docs/configuration.md